# get the first day of the month

Tags: sql-server, date, truncate

I initially started with getting few months back from current date

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())
```

which gives me the date range from three months ago to today, as of today 9/26/2022, the code gave me 6/26/2022. I would like to get up to the first day of June which is 6/1/2022.

However, the following functions according to some googling returned error:

```
DATE_TRUNC(month,DATEADD(month, -3, getdate()))
```

or

```
DATETRUNC(month,DATEADD(month, -3, getdate()))
```

from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

or the trunc_date.

Comment: Better idea: `DATEFROMPARTS( YEAR( SYSUTCDATETIME() ), MONTH( SYSUTCDATETIME ), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 )`.

Comment: Also, avoid `GETDATE()`, instead you should be using UTC in databases - and _not_ using the server's local datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are resolving this only once and not on numerous records.

**Example**

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -3, format(getdate(),'yyyy-MM-01'))
```

or

```
SELECT dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-3,0)
```

**Results**

```
2022-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting? Did you see that `DATETRUNC`...

> Applies to:  SQL Server 2022 (16.x) Preview

Meaning if you aren't running on a very recent preview build of SQL Server 2022, it's not going to work, and this is the error you should be seeing:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10
> 'DATETRUNC' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Another way is to use `EOMONTH()` to get the first day of *next* month, then subtract 4 months instead of 3:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -4, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())));
```

Or `DATEFROMPARTS()`, which is simpler (especially if you perform part of the calculation ahead of time):

```
DECLARE @d date = DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE());

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d), MONTH(@d), 1);
```